# Highchart export, execute function after completion

Tags: highcharts

I need to do some post-processing work on a png file of a Highchart graph. How do I determine when the export is finished? I've tried to attach a function, but it never gets called:

```
console.log("Saving chart...");
chart.exportChart({
  type    : "application/png",
  filename: "tmp_chart_filename"
 },
 function(data) {
   console.log("Export done, Data: " + data); // Not called.
})
console.log("Out");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my understanding, it is not possible out of the box.

What happens internally in the `exportChart()` method is, a form is created on the fly and the chart svg is sent to the server by programmatically triggering a submit on this form. The server in turn, processes received svg into a png (or whatever you may select) and returns it to the browser.

The popup you see that asks you to "save as" is the action of the browser (and not any highchart code) when a file is thrown at it. Basically the returned png is never returned to the code, it goes directly to the browser.

You can however write your [custom svg->png server module](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#exporting.url) and do your magic there :)

Comment: Ok, many thanks for the explanation. To the custom converter it is.

Answer (score 0):

I had a rather similar issue and solved it by defining the [onclick event](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/exporting.buttons.contextButton.onclick) on the contextButton. This seems possible only if you are OK with losing the items in the context menu (export by file type), which wasn't an issue in my case. Below the code to be included in the chart initial building:

```
   [... your Highcharts chart setup ...],

   exporting: {
        buttons: {
             contextButton: {
                  menuItem: null, // You'll lose your menu items here
                  onclick: function(event) {
                       yourFunctionBeforeExport();
                       this.exportChart();
                       yourFunctionAfterExport();
                  }
             }
        }
  }

  [... rest of the Highcharts chart setup ...]
```